# how to upload fixtures to gae datastore?

Tags: django, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, fixtures

I entered: "python manage.py loaddata fixtures\companies.json". It gives me an error.

**What is the proper way to load the json data and then push it to the gae datastore?**

Here is my model:

```
class Company(models.Model):      
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True);
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100);
    address = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True);
    city = models.CharField(max_length=100);
    state = models.CharField(max_length=25);
    zip = models.IntegerField();
    latitude = models.CharField(max_length=20, null=True)
    longitude = models.CharField(max_length=20, null=True)  
    phone = models.CharField(max_length=15, null=True);
    website = models.CharField(max_length=50, null=True);
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=50, null=True);
    hiring = models.BooleanField(default=False);    
    approved = models.BooleanField(default=False);
    date_added = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True);
    about_us = models.TextField(max_length=500, null=True);
```

Here is my fixture:

```
[
    {
        "model": "Companies.Company",
        "fields": {
            "id": 111,
            "name": "1-800 Postcards America's Printing Company",
            "address": "121 Varick Street, 7th Floor",
            "city": "New York",
            "state": "NY",
            "zip": 10013,
            "latitude": "40.724831999999999",
            "longitude": "-74.00609",
            "phone": "212-741-1070",
            "website": "http://www.1800postcards.com",
            "email": "info@1800postcards.com",
            "hiring": "FALSE",
            "approved": "TRUE",
            "date_added": "April 30, 2012, 6:08 p.m.",
            "about_us": "With over 30 years of business experience as full service offset printers and over 200 years of combined knowledge in our production department and press rooms, 1-800Postcards is your professional printer. Our state-of-the-art 125,000 square foot facility is located in the heart of New York City, with an additional web offset plant in New Jersey for our larger orders 500,000 and up. This makes it possible for us to print and mail the highest quality postcards on the market today — at the most competitive rates in the country."
        }
    },
    {
        "model": "Companies.Company",
        "fields": {
            "id": 222,
            "name": "20x200 ",
            "address": "6 Spring Street",
            "city": "New York",
            "state": "NY",
            "zip": 10012,
            "latitude": "40.721052999999998",
            "longitude": "-73.994322999999994",
            "phone": "212-219-0166",
            "website": "http://www.20x200.com/",
            "email": "hello@20x200.com",
            "hiring": "TRUE",
            "approved": "TRUE",
            "date_added": "April 30, 2012, 6:08 p.m.",
            "about_us": "(limited editions × low prices) + the internet = art for everyone. That simple formula, devised by 20x200's founder, Jen Bekman, is what launched 20x200 back in 2007. With that, we set our sights on two core goals: We want everyone to collect art, and we want to enable an economy that allows more artists to make a living by making work. More so, we wanted something as awesome as collecting art to be fun. That's right: fun!"
        }
    },
    {
        "model": "Companies.Company",
        "fields": {
            "id": 333,
            "name": "Adafruit",
            "address": "80 Nassau st #4C",
            "city": "New York",
            "state": "NY",
            "zip": 10038,
            "latitude": "40.709938000000001",
            "longitude": "-74.007987999999997",
            "phone": "646-248-7822",
            "website": "http://www.adafruit.com/",
            "email": "N/A",
            "hiring": "TRUE",
            "approved": "TRUE",
            "date_added": "April 30, 2012, 6:08 p.m.",
            "about_us": "We pride ourselves on having great prices, the best customer service, support and fast shipping. We hope we can assist you on your journey of learning – At Adafruit we celebrate “Engineering Happiness”! Adafruit is a 100% Woman-Owned Small Business."
        }
    }
]
```

Here is the error I get:

```
Problem installing fixture 'fixtures\companies.json': Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Joe\Desktop\My School Stuff\Spring 2012\CS 473\ny-tech\ny-tech\django\core\management\commands\loaddata.py", line 169, in handle
    for obj in objects:
  File "C:\Users\Joe\Desktop\My School Stuff\Spring 2012\CS 473\ny-tech\ny-tech\django\core\serializers\json.py", line 35, in Deserializer
    for obj in PythonDeserializer(simplejson.load(stream), **options):
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\lib\simplejson\simplejson\__init__.py", line 332, in load
    use_decimal=use_decimal, **kw)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\lib\simplejson\simplejson\__init__.py", line 388, in loads
    return _default_decoder.decode(s)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\lib\simplejson\simplejson\decoder.py", line 402, in decode
    obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\lib\simplejson\simplejson\decoder.py", line 418, in raw_decode
    obj, end = self.scan_once(s, idx)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\lib\simplejson\simplejson\scanner.py", line 71, in scan_once
    return _scan_once(string, idx)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\lib\simplejson\simplejson\scanner.py", line 44, in _scan_once
    return parse_array((string, idx + 1), _scan_once)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\lib\simplejson\simplejson\decoder.py", line 284, in JSONArray
    value, end = scan_once(s, end)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\lib\simplejson\simplejson\scanner.py", line 42, in _scan_once
    _scan_once, object_hook, object_pairs_hook, memo)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\lib\simplejson\simplejson\decoder.py", line 230, in JSONObject
    value, end = scan_once(s, end)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\lib\simplejson\simplejson\scanner.py", line 42, in _scan_once
    _scan_once, object_hook, object_pairs_hook, memo)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\lib\simplejson\simplejson\decoder.py", line 230, in JSONObject
    value, end = scan_once(s, end)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\lib\simplejson\simplejson\scanner.py", line 39, in _scan_once
    return parse_string(string, idx + 1, encoding, strict)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\lib\simplejson\simplejson\decoder.py", line 121, in py_scanstring
    content = unicode(content, encoding)
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf8' codec can't decode byte 0x97 in position 484: invalid start byte

Exception AttributeError: "'NoneType' object has no attribute 'mkstemp'" in <bound method DatastoreFileStub.__del__ of <google.appengine.api.datastore_file_stub
.DatastoreFileStub object at 0x02930F10>> ignored
```

Comment: Can you make sure your JSON is valid? Copying and pasting the above into jsonlint.com gives errors. Also, 0x97 refers to the em dash (—), and while I don't know why its inclusion would cause issues, you could try removing it from your JSON.

Comment: @DanHolevoet i see the error, i messed up the TRUE/FALSE fieldss, thanks for jsonlint, never knew there was such a thing!

Comment: Glad to hear it's working now. I posted an answer below for anyone else who has trouble with this type of issue.

Comment: A better solution would be to not load fixtures into the datastore at all, but put them in a file you load into memory.

Comment: @NickJohnson you mean something like puttnig the data in a json file then read from it? we do load that data fairly often though..

Comment: @yaojiang Exactly. You only need to load it once when your instance gets its first request, and store it in memory for the lifetime of the instance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This type of error can occur with invalid JSON. The easiest thing to do is to make sure your JSON validates with [JSON Lint](http://jsonlint.com/), fix any errors it finds, and try the upload again.

Comment: I didn't push my data yet, but I did fix up the json file so no more errors. Thanks again!